# Is there an R or Python function to plot multivariate Gaussian mixtures?

Tags: python, data-visualization, r

Is there a package in R or a library in Python with some functions that allow a graphical representation of a multivariate (2 - dimensional) Gaussian mixture as a joint distribution? By this I mean that I'm not interested in the marginal distributions.

I'm not doing any sort of estimation or approximation, I would just like to visualize the pdf.

By 2-dimensional, I mean that the mixture distribution is a mixture of 2-D normal random variables.

As an example, I would expect something like this, possibly smoother where the two high-density areas meet

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. On the Wikipedia page for [Mixture Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), could you find the kind of plot (or visualization/graphical representation) you want to create? Then please update your question with a reference to that plot (e.g. by mentioning its caption). Thanks.

Comment: I guess that the 2-D part might be confusing. I will update the question

Comment: In python you can use matplotlib for surface plots: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can use the `ggplot2` package. Some functions to do 2D density plots are built-in.

However, it is good visualization practice *not* to rely on 3D graphics for quantitative purposes (see , for example, Kieran Healy's Book [Data Visualization Ch 1](https://socviz.co/lookatdata.html)), because human perception is easily fooled with respect to depth effects, interaction of colors, and readability of axes labels and grids in 3D space.

So you could plot the built-in dataset "faithful" (showing a bimodal distribution of geyser eruptions who are either short and  occuring in quick succession, or big and occuring more rarely);

```
library(ggplot2)      # plotting library
library(viridis)      # use viridis color palette (blue -> yellow)
theme_set(theme_bw()) # white background

# create an "isolines" plot of the data values
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting, y = eruptions)) +
  geom_density_2d() +
        labs(title = "Old Faithful: Geyser Eruptions",
             subtitle = "Isolines plot",
             x ="Waiting times (minutes)",
             y = "Number of Eruptions")
```

[image: isolines]

Alternative

```
# create a plot of the density values which ggplot calculated internally
# (..density.. column)
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting, y = eruptions)) +
  stat_density_2d(
    geom = "tile",
    aes(fill = ..density..),
    contour = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  labs(title = "Old Faithful: Geyser Eruptions",
       subtitle = "Viridis color scale",
       x ="Waiting times (minutes)",
       y = "Number of Eruptions")
```

[image: viridis]

If you really need 3d plots, there are other alternatives. 
Run, for instance, `demo(misc3d::lighting)`, or check answers to question [Plot 3d density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613157/plot-3d-density) on Stackoverflow.